# VB.NET to C++/CLI: How do I import a VB.NET DLL file into C++/CLI?

Tags: vb.net, c++-cli, dllimport

I would like to import a VB.NET DLL file into C++/CLI. I am having trouble referencing my DLL file. I have tried to find tutorials but with no luck, in particular, I usually find how to import managed libraries directly into native code through COM. I would like to import an existing VB.NET DLL file into my C++/CLI project.

Do I require a header file or a declaration file to import and use my VB.NET DLL file?

**Foo.vb**

```
Public Module Foo
    Public Function Bar(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Boolean
        Return a > b
    End Function
End Module
```

**Mixed.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#using "..\Foo\bin\Debug\Foo.dll"
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    bool i = Foo::Bar(10,1);
    Console::WriteLine(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK using a VB.Net dll should be the same as using a DLL from any other .Net language. Can you give any more details? Presumably you are getting some errors on compilation or at run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the discussion in *[Unmanaged C++ to C# interop (replacing CCW)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/07cc852a-4426-471c-9331-27acaf2fa33c/#2666177)*, especially Kuldeep_s last post. It's about accessing a C# DLL file from unmanaged C++ via managed C++. If you skip the umanaged C++ bit it would match your scenario (calling a C# DLL vs a VB.NET DLL shouldn't make any difference).

Comment: THANK YOU! I eventually want to link my vb.net dll to MATLAB. That link helped tremendously.